# How do i answer this question?

Tags: discussion

Under unanswered section I saw this question but unsure how to answer this?

Question is: [What is the difference between a tennis and a racquetball ball?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tennis-and-a-racquetball-ball)

Clearly the question is asking the difference between two balls, just by searching a bit I could easily give the answer but the body of the question is different and is asking:

> What would happen if you played tennis with a racquetball or racquetball with a tennis ball? Tennis balls have felt and are heavier. If I practiced tennis with a racquetball for a week, and then switched to a regular tennis ball, what kind of difference would I feel?

Which is entirely different from the title. This question was asked 1 year 5 months ago and viewed 607 times with no answer.

Which part of question should i give answer to because recently got told that answer on this site should be to the question asked but i'm seeing at least 3 questions.

Just joined this site and still not familiar with all of the rule. But there are other unanswered question like this.

Answer (score 4):

> Titles are a reference label, a brief description of the question so it can be found by later searches; they do not form the whole question, or even a relevant part of it.
>
> ...

Answer the question. Don't answer the title.

The question is what difference would be felt if the ball of one sport was used to play the other, and implicitly, how would this affect the play.

Answer (score 4):

My personal view: this is not a particularly good question as it's unclear which point the OP actually wants answered:

- What is the difference between a tennis and a racquetball ball? (i.e a simple factual question about sizes, weights, etc)
- What would happen if you played tennis with a racquetball or racquetball with a tennis ball? (i.e. what effect would it have on the game)
- If I practiced tennis with a racquetball for a week, and then switched to a regular tennis ball, what kind of difference would I feel? (i.e. what effect would it have on a player)

These are at least two, and possibly three, separate questions. Therefore what I'd do here is to vote to close the question as "too broad" and not answer it unless it is clarified. I appreciate you may not be able to vote to close yet, but the second half still applies - we shouldn't feel the need to answer every question on the site just because they're there.